# Sandwich bun / Bun sandwich?

Tags: word-request

How do you call this:

[image: bun]

**Sandwich bun** or **bun sandwich**?

Comment: It's  sandwich bun. BTW why didn't you do a simple research to figure this out?

Comment: Because google gives you both options and I didn't even know if I was using the right "name". Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Ahh. The best partners you get when trying to find out how much something is used is [Google n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sandwich+bun%2C+bun+sandwich&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csandwich%20bun%3B%2Cc0) and COCA. In this case, n-gram was reliably clear on which one is correct usage, but COCA returned three and two results for each of them, which is unreliable.

Comment: I call it *a burger!* (InE).

Comment: The name seems to depend on what you mean: the whole shebang or just the baked products that bookend the filling. (0:

Comment: @CopperKettle The whole thing.

Comment: @MaulikV - I don't see any burger in there.  To me, the *sine qua non* of a burger is the hamburger patty itself, and this doesn't seem to have one.

Comment: If you see the bracket.... :) @stangdon

Comment: the question seems to be *regional*!

Comment: @MaulikV - I can't argue with that!  It just seems very strange to me.  :-)

Comment: @MaulikV I don't understand why you put "(InE)" in your [comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75609/sandwich-bun-bun-sandwich#comment145714_75609) because everywhere it is called "burger." :) Sometimes also called "sandwich" :(

Comment: @Usernew - This may be a matter of regional usage.  In American English, a "burger" or "hamburger" is a patty of ground beef (or sometimes other substitute meat, but beef is the original and standard) or a sandwich made with a bun and the ground beef patty.  I don't know what that thing in the middle of the sandwich in the picture is, but it looks more like a piece of sausage.  If I ordered a burger and got that thing in the picture, I would send it back.

Comment: @stangdon I think you missed my point. I am very well aware of [Hamburger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger). :) BTW, the thing in the pic seems like pork meat.

Comment: Check stangdon's comment! It proves that *InE* worked! @Usernew In India, *sandwich* is *[strictly this](http://www.vegrecipesofindia.com/veg-cheese-toast-sandwich-recipe/) (at least in half of India I have visited/lived!)* Sandwiches are *never round* as shown in the picture.

Comment: @stangdon strangely, *in India*, we *don't* care what's **in** it! We call these things by their *shapes!* Said that, anything that is inside two round breads is *burger*. If it contains some potato/fried thing, it's *[Aloo tikki burger](http://cdn.firstwefeast.com/assets/2013/06/mcindia_mcaloo_tikki-Brand-Eating.jpg)*, if it has just vegetables, it's *Veg burger*. If it has *paneer*, it is *Paneer burger!* and so on! On the other hand, anything's in between square shaped breads, it's *[sandwich](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-FrgnkHGyJ5g/UhBXU9Cez-I/AAAAAAAAhiw/zjBoyoKNtxM/s1600/s+start.jpg)!*

Comment: @MaulikV To me, and my friends, a sandwich is anything that's served as a filling between two pieces of bread, irrespective of shape. [This](http://subsconscious.com/sites/default/files/hero_001jpg.jpg), we call it a sandwich, [this](http://www.bluelemonbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/egg-mayo-sandwich.jpg), and [this](http://assets.jackinthebox.com/products/28/image/large_ChickenSandwich.png), too!

Comment: @stangdon Originally, it contained **steak** instead of **ham**, but it was still called "hamburger" because it originated in the Hamburg city. Even Americans can argue over what it's called: Sandwich or Burger. In toady's world, Hamburger is exactly like what you and I said.

Comment: @Usernew the first one is *hotdog* for us! The second one is *sandwich* and the third one is *burger*. Said that, long bread -hotdog, square cut in triangle -sandwich, round -burger! Period! haha

Comment: @MaulikV For your knowledge, that's still a sandwich! Hotdog is technically a ***sausage of minced beef or pork.*** If you go to any Subway restaurant, and you ask them for a "hotdog,"  they will say that they serve sandwiches, not hotdogs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32944/discussion-between-usernew-and-maulik-v).

Answer (score 2):

The entire thing is a *sandwich*.  The bread specifically is what (not how) is called a *bun*, and if it's meant for a sandwich, then it's called a *sandwich bun*.

Answer (score 2):

The bread is called a "sandwich bun". The whole thing is simply a "sandwich". If you wanted to specify that it is a sandwich that uses a bun rather than regular bread or a muffin or whatever, I don't think there's a concise phrase. You'd have to say "a sandwich on a bun" or "a sandwich made with a bun" or some such.